# How to send 2 strings using Notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent

I'm trying to send 2 strings using Notification, but I don't know how should I do it. I used putExtra for my strings, but on the other activity I get null. I don't know what to do on the other activity. I read about this on net, but I didn't undersand. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code :

```
private void setNotifiy(){
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence NotificationTicket = "You have a notification";

    //CharSequence NotificationContent = ;
    CharSequence contentTitle =  "You are close to "+name_shop+"!!!";
    CharSequence contentText ="So,you can go for shopping:)";

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            NotificationTicket, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ShopsOnMap.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("latshop",lat_choose);

    notificationIntent.putExtra("longshop", long_choose);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);


    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

}
```

In the class ShopsOnMap I wrote just this :

```
String q = getIntent().getStringExtra("latshop");
System.out.println("!!"+q+"$$");
```

and I obtain q=null.

I need a simple example, or any idea that could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `lat_choose` is not null?

Comment: I put System.out.println(lat_choose) and it is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in your `getActivity()` call, instead of `0`, for the fourth parameter, so your new `Intent` extras are applied to the `PendingIntent`.